# Get VID And PID from keypress

Tags: c#, keypress

Does anybody know if it's possible to get the VID and PID from a keypress event in C#?

I've been searching, and seems like it's possible with C, but I can't find any examples for C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for the VID (Vendor ID) and PID (Product ID) of the USB device that generated a keypress.  There is no direct support for this in C#, so you will need to use P/Invoke to access the C "raw input" API.

Here are two examples to start from:

- [Distinguishing Barcode Scanners from the Keyboard in WinForms](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/)
- [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)

Comment: I've tried both, and can't actually get any of them to work. 

The last one doesn't fire the event, and the first one I'll get some strange error message, and I've tried to through the configuration management to set everything to x64